# Question on a paper by Shnider and Sternberg

Tags: representation-theory, hopf-algebras, deformation-theory, coalgebras

I'm reading the [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869384712890) 'The cobar resolution and a restricted deformation theory' by S. Shnider and S. Sternberg. I do not understand the definition of the map $\delta_p$ defined in section $3$. The problem is that I'm unsure on what is meant by $\text{Ad}(\Psi_{i,p+1})$. I've looked at their book 'Quantum groups' and on page $20$ the letters $\text{Ad}$ are also used, but very differently. Other than that it is quite clear what the intention of the paper is.

Comment: I think this question would deserve a try at http://mathoverflow.net/.